# How to fill jasper report using criteria.uniqueResult();?

Tags: java, hibernate, jasper-reports

I want to view report by using `customerId`.

> `JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, ?, ?);// How to fill?`

I tried :
    `BLManager.java`

```
public void report(int custId) throws JRException, FileNotFoundException {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Customer.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("custId", custId));
        Customre customer = (Customer) criteria.uniqueResult();

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("src/com/customer/reports/report.jrxml");
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

        JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport) JasperCompileManager.compileReport(bis);
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, ?, ?);// How to fill?

        JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint, false);
    }
```

Further I calling this method on `buttonClick`
`Client Class`

```
@FXML
private void viewReport(ActionEvent e) {
    Customer customer = customerTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    if (customer != null) {
        int custId = customer.getCustId();
        try {
            bLManager.report(custId);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException | JRException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FollowUpController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have 2 options, 1. put the Customre in the parameter map (? one) and pass JREmptyDatasource() in ? two, then use the for example the title band and display the data in parameter. 2. Pass an empty parameter map in ? one and create a JRBeanCollectionDatasource (adding Customre in a List), then use the detail band to display data.

Comment: Overall currently this question is a bit unclear/too broad, you need to study some and understand both of your question marks. First ? is the the parameter map, study what it does and how to use it in jrxml, second is a connection or a JRDatasource, study how to use it in jrxml. Once you have the basic, try and if still problem post also your jrxml creating a [mcve]

Comment: Thanks for attention.  I don't need to use a List since I'm looking for unique field.

Comment: I understand either use the parameter map then, or create the List anyway so you can easily create the JRBeanCollectionDatasource, seems useless to create the List but I would probably have gone for this solution, since maybe 1 day I need to print more then one, hence report will also work if you need to print multiple

Comment: To answer this question see:  http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperFillManager.html#fillReportToFile-java.lang.String-java.util.Map-net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource- :)

Comment: I tried with list but it is helpless since I want to retrieve an unique value.

Comment: I need  to specify connection in second ?.

Comment: No, you don't need connection since you have the bean, if you are doing it with a List create a JRBeanCollectionDatasource from the List and pass that.

Comment: I shouldn't use List cause I want unique value to generate report. for example want to generate report of 1st number id. That I'll give input 1 from textfield

Comment: that's why at second ? I'm thinking to specify connection

Comment: Why?, listen, I know you have only 1, but trust me pass a JRBeanCollectionDataSource, (that you create from a List, yes only 1 record), but then your report is easy to make, create fields with name as your bean, put the textField in detail band (this will iterate 1 time, since unique).. The day you wan't to print 2 records you pass 2 records in List.

Comment: There is the other solution to pass the bean in parameter map and not specify anything in 3 parameter, but this is more complex, since you will not have detail band, you need to put all fields in title or in summary band, then you need to call the methods on your parameter, you need to set report to display all even if datasource is empty etc... It's more work then creating a normal/starndard datasource... Yes it's only 1 record but who cares and maybe one day you like to display more then 1 record.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200700/discussion-between-swapnil-and-petter-friberg).

Answer (score 1):

When you use `fillReport` method of `JasperFillManager`, you can pass a `parameterMap`.

A `parameterMap` is a `HashMap` where you put as key the name of paramter managed by the report, and as value the object instance.

This is my code to fill `parameterMap` (you can use as example for your case):

```
Map<String, Object> parameterMap = new HashMap<String, Object>;
parameterMap.put("datasource", jRdataSource);
parameterMap.put("MyComplexObject", myComplexObject); // you can pass a pojo
parameterMap.put("Title", "My report title");
```

You can see [***the documentation about JasperFillManager methods here***](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperFillManager.html#fillReport-java.io.InputStream-java.util.Map-)

Comment: Well I had used map but it was difficult to do, I mean I was getting an exception as no  such method from where I was designing a query in jrxml that was not matching with pojo fields.

Comment: When you use a parameter map, in Jasper you must use Parameter object to process. If you want, post your code to further answer

Comment: I used JDBC instead but I'm facing slower speed of report generation. [Jasper Reports 6.7.0 generating report is slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58389318/jasper-reports-6-7-0-generating-report-is-slow) I've asked here.

Comment: @Swapnil: I've written a comment to your question about report performance

Comment: I've checked it. Thanks for attention and time